# What's the name for the string attached to a zipper to help close or open a bag?

Tags: vocabulaire, demande-de-mot, habillement

What's the name for the string attached to a zipper to help close or open a bag?

[image]

Comment: For reference and dictionary consultation, in English I would call that a "pull", "string", "tab", or "pull tab" depending on whether it's indeed  just a string/loop or a flat grippable piece of metal or plastic or both.

Comment: @LukeSawczak thanks, I was indeed [wondering](https://ell.stackexchange.com/q/273876/3023) what the name English is.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The image shows a string attached directly to the slider of the [zipper](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zipper) and not to its pull tab, which is seemingly missing. The pull tab is a [*tirette*](https://www.btb.termiumplus.gc.ca/tpv2alpha/alpha-eng.html?lang=eng&i=1&srchtxt=TIRETTE&index=alt&codom2nd_wet=TN#resultrecs); the string is used as a replacement for it in the image:

> [Cordon](https://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/cordon)(/[sangle](https://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/sangle)/[languette](https://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/languette)) servant de tirette.

Or the string is "connected" to the pull tab by its nature:

> [Cordon](https://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/cordon)(/[sangle](https://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/sangle)/[languette](https://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/languette)) de [of the] tirette.

If the string was attached to the pull tab per se, then it's like an extension:

> [Rallonge](https://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/rallonge) à/de tirette.

Metonymic use might simply be ***tirette***; some may reference its material (*...en corde, en tissu*).

In the end the *tirette* will go a long way...

Comment: Great suggestions, thanks!

Comment: @FranckDernoncourt Welcome! Maybe someone else finds something which is more grounded in experience, or maybe along the lines of "grab" or "helper" in French something. Guess we'll see.

Answer (score 1):

Another suggestion based on [Zéhontée Bonteuse](https://french.stackexchange.com/users/26366/z%c3%a9hont%c3%a9e-bonteuse)'s great [answer](https://french.stackexchange.com/a/44437/839):

> [Rallonge](https://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/rallonge) à/de tirette *en forme de boucle*.

It is longer but help communicate the shape of the rallonge.

Comment: Imagine the first-aid kit is in there: "ouvre le sac!  Tire sur la rallonge de tirette en forme de boucle!" 